# Global update for options price Opencart

Tags: php, database, opencart

I looking for some suggestions about how to make/update option price in all products ?
im using opecart 3 here is link options features
http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/catalog/option/

Default opencart options are created in one tab and than in each product you can add this options with price that cool, but when you need to update price of current option you need to do it one by one product . how can i do something global that will update option price and will reflect all products that include this option ?

What i tried is to create one MAIN product that have current options with price and custom module to add this MAIN product option in another products so at the end you can edit only the MAIN product option price and that will reflect all other , but later i face some problems

i create in DB another table where is record current product_id , product_id_option (this is the MAIN product_id) and option_id that you add for current product

but here i face the problem

```
www.pastebin.com/d8wtpp75
```

for example current $product_id = 50
but options that should pull are for MAIN $product_id = 100

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i create one MAIN product that have current options with price and custom module to add this  MAIN product option in another products so at the end you can edit only the main product option price that will reflect all other , but i face the problem when cart have to calculate total price for product and options

Comment: Please add everything you've tried so far (including the code in question) to your question, along with the problems you're facing

Comment: ok i add some extra information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some solutions that come to mind

### 1. Use export/import to excel.

You can use a module that exports all the products or filtered product to an excel file where you can easily update the values and upload back in.

[Export/Import Pro](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31314)

### 2. Use a batch product editor module

Use a module that basically does the same as the export/import only via the admin interface.

[Batch product editor](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=32157)

### 3. Use a master product to update slave products

This is the option you wrote in your question. Basically create a master product that when updated, updates the other products. I made a module for you called ms_product_option (master slave product option only for OC v3.x)

here are the steps required.

1. add controller with path 
   `admin/controller/extension/module/ms_product_option.php` .

```php
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMSProductOption extends Controller {
    private $error = array();
    private $codename = 'ms_product_option';

    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/ms_product_option');

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('setting/setting');


        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('module_ms_product_option', $this->request->post);

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            $this->load->model('setting/event');
            $this->model_setting_event->deleteEventByCode($this->codename);

            if($this->request->post['module_ms_product_option_status']){
                $this->model_setting_event->addEvent($this->codename, 'admin/model/catalog/product/editProduct/after', 'extension/module/ms_product_option/model_catalog_product_editProduct_after');
                $this->model_setting_event->addEvent($this->codename, 'admin/view/catalog/product_form/before', 'extension/module/ms_product_option/view_catalog_product_form_before');
            }

            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=module', true));
        }

        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_extension'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=module', true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module/ms_product_option', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true)
        );

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/ms_product_option', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true);

        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=module', true);

        if (isset($this->request->post['module_ms_product_option_status'])) {
            $data['module_ms_product_option_status'] = $this->request->post['module_ms_product_option_status'];
        } else {
            $data['module_ms_product_option_status'] = $this->config->get('module_ms_product_option_status');
        }

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/ms_product_option', $data));
    }

    protected function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/module/ms_product_option')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }

    public function install(){
        $this->load->model('extension/module/ms_product_option');
        $this->model_extension_module_ms_product_option->installDatabase();
    }

    public function uninstall(){
        $this->load->model('extension/module/ms_product_option');
        $this->model_extension_module_ms_product_option->deleteDatabase();

        $this->load->model('setting/event');
        $this->model_setting_event->deleteEventByCode($this->codename);
    }

    //OC event to trigger update of slave products
    public function model_catalog_product_editProduct_after(&$route, &$data, &$output){
        $this->load->model('extension/module/ms_product_option');
        //check if master product
        if($this->model_extension_module_ms_product_option->isProductMaster($data[0])){
            $master_product_id = $data[0];
            //trigger update of slaves

            $this->model_extension_module_ms_product_option->updateProductsOptionsFromProductMaster($master_product_id);
        }else{
            $product_id = $data[0];
            $this->model_extension_module_ms_product_option->deleteProductFromProductMaster($product_id);
            if(!empty($data[1]['master_product_id'])){
                $master_product_id = $data[1]['master_product_id'];

                $this->model_extension_module_ms_product_option->addProductToProductMaster($product_id, $master_product_id);
            }
        }


    }
    public function view_catalog_product_form_before(&$route, &$data){
        if($data && isset($this->request->get['product_id'])){
            $product_id = $this->request->get['product_id'];
            $this->load->model('extension/module/ms_product_option');

            $product_info = $this->model_extension_module_ms_product_option->getMasterProductOfProduct($product_id);

            if($product_info){
                $data['master_product_id'] = $product_info['master_product_id'];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

2. add model with path `admin/model/extension/module/ms_product_option.php`

```php
<?php
class ModelExtensionModuleMSProductOption extends Model {

    public function installDatabase() {
        $this->db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "ms_product_option` (
          `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `master_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;");
    }

    public function deleteDatabase() {
        $this->db->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "ms_product_option`");

    }

    public function isProductMaster($master_product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "ms_product_option` WHERE master_product_id = '" . (int)$master_product_id . "'");
        if($query->rows){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function addProductToProductMaster($product_id, $master_product_id) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "ms_product_option` SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', master_product_id = '" . (int)$master_product_id . "'");
    }

    public function deleteProductFromProductMaster($product_id) {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "ms_product_option WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    }

    public function getProductsOfProductMaster($master_product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "ms_product_option` msp2p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (msp2p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND msp2p.master_product_id = '".(int) $master_product_id. "'");
        return $query->rows;
    }

    public function getMasterProductOfProduct($product_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "ms_product_option` WHERE product_id = '".(int) $product_id. "'");
        return $query->row;
    }

    public function updateProductsOptionsFromProductMaster($master_product_id) {
        //get product master options
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $data['product_option'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($master_product_id);

        //get list of products connected to product master
        $products = $this->getProductsOfProductMaster($master_product_id);

        //update options
        foreach($products as $product){
            $product_id = $product['product_id'];
            if (isset($data['product_option'])) {
                foreach ($data['product_option'] as $product_option) {
                    if ($product_option['type'] == 'select' || $product_option['type'] == 'radio' || $product_option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $product_option['type'] == 'image') {
                        if (isset($product_option['product_option_value'])) {
                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', required = '" . (int)$product_option['required'] . "'");

                            $product_option_id = $this->db->getLastId();

                            foreach ($product_option['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
                                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['option_value_id'] . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product_option_value['quantity'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$product_option_value['subtract'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_option_value['price'] . "', price_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['price_prefix']) . "', points = '" . (int)$product_option_value['points'] . "', points_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['points_prefix']) . "', weight = '" . (float)$product_option_value['weight'] . "', weight_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['weight_prefix']) . "'");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', value = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option['value']) . "', required = '" . (int)$product_option['required'] . "'");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. add language file with path `admin/language/en-gb/extension/module/ms_product_option.php`

```php
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']    = '<span style="color:#449DD0; font-weight:bold">MS Product Option</span><span style="font-size:12px; color:#999"> by <a href="http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_username=Dreamvention" style="font-size:1em; color:#999" target="_blank">Dreamvention</a></span>';

// Text
$_['text_extension']   = 'Extensions';
$_['text_success']     = 'Success: You have modified MS Product Option module!';
$_['text_edit']        = 'Edit MS Product Option Module';

// Entry
$_['entry_status']     = 'Status';

// Error
$_['error_permission'] = 'Warning: You do not have permission to modify MS Product Option module!';
```

4. add twig file with path `admin/view/template/extension/module/ms_product_option.twig`

```
{{ header }}{{ column_left }}
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-module" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_save }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href="{{ cancel }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_cancel }}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
      <h1>{{ heading_title }}</h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        {% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
        <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    {% if error_warning %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> {{ error_warning }}
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> {{ text_edit }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="{{ action }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-module" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-status">{{ entry_status }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="module_ms_product_option_status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                {% if module_ms_product_option_status %}
                <option value="1" selected="selected">{{ text_enabled }}</option>
                <option value="0">{{ text_disabled }}</option>
                {% else %}
                <option value="1">{{ text_enabled }}</option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected">{{ text_disabled }}</option>
                {% endif %}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{ footer }}
```

5. add ocmod file with path `system/ms_product_option.ocmod.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>ms_product_option</name>
    <code>ms_product_option</code>
    <description>MS Product Option</description>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <author>Dreamvention</author>
    <link>http://dreamvention.ee</link>
    <file path="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-option">]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
            <!-- //ms_product_option.xml 1 -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-model">Master Product</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" name="master_product_id" value="{{ master_product_id }}" placeholder="master product id" id="input-model" class="form-control" />
                  </div>
              </div>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

6. (optional) add a shopunity json file with path `system/library/d_shopunity/extension/ms_product_option.json` if you are using https://shopunity.net

```
{
    "codename": "ms_product_option",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "MS Product Option",
    "description": "Create Master products and connect slave products. When updating options in saster product, you will automatically update slave products.",
    "index": "extension/d_shopunity",
    "author": {
        "name": "Dreamvention",
        "email": "info@dreamvention.com",
        "url": "https://dreamvention.ee/"
    },
    "opencart_version": [
        "3.0.0.0",
        "3.0.1.1",
        "3.0.1.2",
        "3.0.2.0"
    ],
    "type": "module",
    "license": {
        "type": "free",
        "url": "https://shopunity.net/licenses/free"
    },
    "install": {
        "url": "extension/module/install&extension=ms_product_option",
        "xml": "system/library/d_shopunity/install/ms_product_option.xml"
    },
    "uninstall": {
        "url": "extension/module/uninstall&extension=ms_product_option"
    },
    "support": {
        "email": "support@dreamvention.com",
        "url": "https://dreamvention.ee/support"
    },
    "required":{
        "d_opencart_patch": ">=1.0.0"
    },
    "files": [
        "system/library/d_shopunity/extension/ms_product_option.json",

        "admin/controller/extension/module/ms_product_option.php",
        "admin/model/extension/module/ms_product_option.php",
        "admin/language/en-gb/extension/module/ms_product_option.php",
        "admin/view/template/extension/module/ms_product_option.twig",

        "system/library/d_shopunity/install/ms_product_option.xml"
    ],
    "changelog": [
        {
            "version":"1.0.0",
            "change": "Initial commit"
        }
    ]
}
```

> I also uploaded the files packaged into a standard opencart module so you can installed it via OpenCart extension installer

https://github.com/Dreamvention/youtube_files/tree/master/ms_product_option